# Обособление «чур»

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Чур(,) не я!

> Лео(,) чур(,) не пойдёт туда.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нужно — это междометие, хотя «Грамота» не выделяет. Странно.